# Retrieve the target object of many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm creating a many to many through relationship to create a follow/follower relationship

User -> Relationship -> User

I want to retrieve all the User objects following a particular User but currently all I can do is retrieve a queryset of Relationship objects.

Comment: What is your specific problem? Also, please, post the code you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is:

```
User.objects.filter(to_relationships__user=self)
                                    ^^
```

the double underscore allows you to query across relationships